# How to do auto OTP filling in MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to convert my Xamrin project to MAUI. In my Xamrine project, I use the "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth" package. But when I tried this in MAUI I got this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you need to add the following NuGet package to your project:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Jvm

Try installing the latest see if that works out